# Как поменять имя пользователя OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt

Вопрос по настройке уже установленной на роутер системы OpenWRT: как поменять имя пользователя? Вместо стандартного root.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]. задайте, пожалуйста, отдельные вопросы. здесь так принято: один вопрос — один (и более) ответов на него.

Comment: [Secure your router's access](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access)